# Unity. Is there a way to link objects in List to them specific animations which are in another List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two lists in unity first is `List<GameObject> objList`, second is `List<Animator> animList`. So I need somehow to link first object from GameObject list with first animation from Animator list, second with second and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you have a custom script which holds your gameobject and corresponding animator together and then have a list of that very custom script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well are the `GameObject`s of the first list the same once the `Animator` components are attached to?

In this case you really only need the `animList` and whenever you access an item you already have the [`Animator.gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) reference anyway.

```
var obj = animList[0].gameObject;
```

the other way round would be also possible though of course a bit more expensive if nowhere cached

```
var anim = objList[0].GetComponent<Animator>();
```

here you could have more flexibility with the relation ship by e.g. using `GetComponentInChildren` if you know that it is not exactly on this object but a child.

---

Otherwise I would just have a class

```
[Serializable]
public class AnimatorObjectPair
{
    public Animator animator;
    public GameObject gameObject;
}
```

and then only store a list of

```
public List<AnimatorObjectPair> animatorObjectPairs;
```

and populate that one instead of the individual lists so you always access both references together.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to make a class that have the both fields and make a list with this custom class. If this can't happen you don't have a "proper built-in" way to link one to another, unless you use a dictionary, you'll need to make sure that every time you access your first value in list A you will also access first item on list B

Comment: *"you'll need to make sure that every time you access your first value in list A you will also access first item on list B"* ... and ensure they stay in sync (ordering, items, etc.).

Comment: Yap, @ChiefTwoPencils is right, this isn't really a good approach, it's hard to have a guarantee about this sync, highly recommend a custom way with both fieds